# Installing Skype failed; code 1638 when trying to upgrade Skype

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1, skype

My Skype version is `6.20.0.104`. When I open it on Windows 8.1 with Update, it cues me to upgrade:

> The latest version of Skype is ready to install now. It won't take long to upgrade - and you'll get all the latest improvements and fixes.

[image: Updates are ready to install]

After going through the next > next > next of the upgrade, Skype complains as follows.

> Another version of this product is already installed. Installation of this version cannot continue. To configure or remove the existing version of this product, use Add/Remove Programs in

[image: Installing Skype failed; code 1638]

When looking in Add/Remove Programs, Skype is not listed:

[image: Skype is not listed in Add/Remove Programs]

How can I upgrade Skype to get all the latest improvements and fixes?

Answer (score 3):

Windows installer could not find **Skype** in installed software list and hence the error. 
I was able to resolve this issue after uninstalling Skype by manipulating MSI file available at `C:\ProgramData\Skype\65DDDF6CCAB61F017E87A987E1BBB31DA098BBA6\`

1. Open Command Prompt in Administrator mode
2. Navigate to `C:\ProgramData\Skype\65DDDF6CCAB61F017E87A987E1BBB31DA098BBA6`
3. Run `msiexex /x skype.msi`
4. Re-install Skype

Comment: Interesting. I have two skype.msi files. One is in `C:\ProgramData\Skype\{24991BA0-F0EE-44AD-9CC8-5EC50AECF6B7}` and the other is in `C:\ProgramData\Skype\{7A3C7E05-EE37-47D6-99E1-2EB05A3DA3F7}`. Thank you for the tip.

Answer (score 3):

well .. i tried with Microsoft Fixit .. not helping.

I just looked for the latest SkypeSetup.msi installer file from here:
http://www.skype.com/go/getskype-msi

1. Download the file.
2. right click msi file and select "uninstall"
3. remove all skype files from folders "Program Files", "Program Data" and %temp%
4. right click msi file and select "install"
5. VIOLA! I ve installed latest Skype and it is listed in Control Panel/Program as well.

Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to uninstall Skype by running the Microsoft Fixit - [Fix problems that programs cannot be installed or uninstalled](http://support2.microsoft.com/mats/program_install_and_uninstall/en). Simply follow the onscreen instructions to uninstall Skype. Then download and reinstall the most recent Skype version.