# Remove Skype completely

Tags: windows-10, skype, uninstall

I was trying to update Skype and it gave me this message

[image: Installing Skupe failed; code 1638]

I went to `Programs and Features` to uninstall it, but I couldn't find 'Skype' in the list. I deleted the Skype directory manually in `Program Files` and also `Program Data` and tried to install again. It gave me the same message. I really want to use Skype so that I am communicate with my friends. Btw, Java is missing from the list too.

Comment: Before you manually removed it was Skype working?

Comment: How many user accounts are on this PC? Are there any Skype plugins installed in the browers/other programs

Comment: @Ramhound, I manually removed it after it isn't working.@Dave, one and nope

Comment: @Ramhound It doesn't help me

Comment: At this point, you might want to try [Revo Uninstaller](http://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) to clean up.

Answer (score 1):

To remove Skype (or most programs) completely, check the Program and Features, find it and uninstall this way (even though you said you did this).

After this is done do a simple search in C:\Program Files and C:\Program Files(x86) if it exists for any Skype folders. If you find any, delete those too.

Search in your registry for any Skype components. Press windows key + r then type 'regedit' and click ok. Navigate to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Skype and delete this entire folder.

**Alternate method:**

Download, but don’t run this installer for the latest version.

Using the procedure described here,

http://community.skype.com/t5/Windows-archive/How-to-update-Skype-without-using-any-Skype-installer/m-p/707359

extract the Skype.exe file from the SkypeSetup.msi file and replace your currently installed Skype.exe with this new Skype.exe file. You will be now running the latest Skype version.

After this, there should be no parts of Skype remaining.

Comment: There is no Skype in program and features(http://prntscr.com/8qt0ah). I deleted the registry but I still get the same error

Comment: Have you looked at this SU answer? Seems like this may help you: http://superuser.com/questions/848742/installing-skype-failed-code-1638-when-trying-to-upgrade-skype

Comment: Yes I did. Tried the method but it didn't work

Comment: Did Microsoft Fixit uninstall it fine?

Comment: I added another method for you to try in my answer

Comment: "We're sorry, but your operating system is not supported by Microsoft Fix it at this time. " - MS FixIt. Also, I don't want to do that because updating skype will be a problem

Comment: "Updating skype will be a problem"? Isn't it a problem now?

Comment: Installing skype is, since skype was already "installed". When a new update is available, Skype uninstalls itself then install the new updated Skype

Comment: I still think this would be your best bet since traditional methods aren't working. Once you get it working, then the next version might handle it better possibly. At least this way, you'd have a working skype app.